# Comparing changes in commits to the current file by Git

Tags: git

**How can you show the differences of a file in the last 5 commits to the current uncommitted file by Git-show?**

I made a change to my file which breaks my code. However, I do not know where the change is.

I would like to compare the current uncommitted files to the recent commit (HEAD), to the previous commit (^HEAD) and at least 3 commits deeper.

However, I do not know how you can do it efficiently.

In trying to see the changes of the five last commits of one file to the current file in the given branch, I unsuccessfully ran

```
git show next~5:handle_questions.php
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is my cheat-sheet:

```
# uncommited file to HEAD
git diff <path>

# uncommited file to before last commit
git diff HEAD^ -- <path>

#last commit to before last commit
git diff HEAD^ HEAD -- <path>

#difference between HEAD and n-th grandparent
git diff HEAD~n HEAD -- <path>

#Another cool feature is whatchanged command
git whatchanged -- <path>
```

Comment: how would you do uncommitted file against a different filepath from last commit?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Description of git diff: "Show changes between the working tree and the index or a tree, changes between the index and a tree, changes between two trees, or changes between two files on disk."

Comment: I was wondering what the `--` meant in the commands above? Then I remembered it's used in many bash built-in commands to signify the end of options (i.e. only positional args after `--`). Thus, the `--` is not required, but only paths go after `--`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/146742

Answer (score 4):

To see the diff between handle_questions.php in the working directory and in the repository 5 commits back, use:

```
$ git diff HEAD~5 handle_questions.php
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use git bisect to track down the commit which introduced a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the file that the change was made in, you can also use `git blame <path>` - this will give you ahistory of each line of code in the following format:

```
SHA (Author Timestamp Line Number) code
```

Answer (score 0):

From @db_ answer (but shown as an actual example)

I just want to see what difference there is between the current file and the last commit for just a single file.

```
git diff scripts/processQueue.php


-  if( filemtime( $filename ) < time() - 10 ) {
+  $filemtime=filemtime($filename);
+  if( $filemtime < time() - 10 && $filemtime> (time() - 86400))
```